# replace all names in a dataframe based on another list

Tags: r

I was struggling by replacing all names in one dataframe using another table. I would like to replace values based on a separate table. Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

my Dictionary:

```
dic.txt:
```

========

```
human    AATC,AGGTA,ATTCAT
mouse    TTTT,CCCC
dog      ATGGG,TTTTAA

dic <- read.table("dic.txt",header=F)
```

and a table.txt like:

```
mouse   human
dog     mouse

dic <- read.table("dic.txt",header=F)
```

And I would like to replace the values in table with the corresponding values in dic.txt

```
TTTT,CCCC   AATC,AGGTA,ATTCAT
ATGGG,TTTTAA     TTTT,CCCC
```

I can do it in perl or python but I have to do it as a piece od code in a R program

Comment: Great! perfect! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match()`, matching the first column of `dic` with the unlisted `table`.  Then we use the resulting integer values to extract our desired values from the second column of `dic`.

```
table[] <- dic$V2[match(unlist(table), dic$V1)]
```

which gives the updated `table`

```
table
#             V1                V2
# 1    TTTT,CCCC AATC,AGGTA,ATTCAT
# 2 ATGGG,TTTTAA         TTTT,CCCC
```

**Data:**

```
dic <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("dog", 
"human", "mouse"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
2L), .Label = c("AATC,AGGTA,ATTCAT", "ATGGG,TTTTAA", "TTTT,CCCC"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

table <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("dog", "mouse"
), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("human", 
"mouse"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: @Riah Scriven, if I have  some extra columns in table.txt, how can I handle that without affecting other columns (only col 1,2 replaced and the rest remain intact). what I have done is not correct table[,1:2] <- dic$V2[match(unlist(table[,1:2]), dic$V1)]

Comment: @user6013305 - You could write up a new question for that.  It's a lot different from this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with two input data frames dic & tbl):

```
names(dic) <- c('species', 'dna')
names(tbl) <- c('species1', 'species2')

dic
  species               dna
1   human AATC,AGGTA,ATTCAT
2   mouse         TTTT,CCCC
3     dog      ATGGG,TTTTAA

tbl
  species1 species2
1    mouse    human
2      dog    mouse

merge(merge(dic, tbl, by.x='species', by.y='species1'), 
            dic, by.x='species2', by.y='species')[3:4]

     dna.x             dna.y
1    TTTT,CCCC AATC,AGGTA,ATTCAT
2 ATGGG,TTTTAA         TTTT,CCCC
```